# define, that the user came from specific page? (in PHP)

Tags: php

Is there the way in PHP to define, that the user came from specific page? without "post" requests.
I have a "add post" page. when user submit a post, on the next page he can submit some more information. But when user click "back" in browser he returns to blank "add post" form, and what I need is that the user can modify previously submitted info, but only if he presses back from this second page.

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` - doesn't seem to work.
Maybe I can set some data in `$_SESSION` on second page and celar it on every other page except the first.. but its seems like not very smart.

Comment: @Grom S, why don't you make an edit button that returns to the previous page but and has all the form fields filled out? You could check for a specific session value when entering that page to determine if it's an edit or a new submission.

Comment: why should a session not be very smart? Your scenarion is what it's implemented for..

Comment: @Nick yes, i can do it. but what if user prefer "back" button in browser. or maybe the design is not very user friendly. after all i can't be shure that user do not click back button..

Comment: @Grom S, if the design isn't very user friendly I think you need to make it user friendly rather. If your edit button stands out enough, the user may try to use that first.

Comment: @freddy K because i need to clear it in every page. as i understand. what if somewhan creates new pages later?

Comment: @Nick what if i'm not designer) and i don't get money for it)

Comment: @Grom S, tell the designer you're not a designer and you can still tell his design sucks? Seriously though, you could try using an iframe in the final page so the back button won't work, or you could just deal with the user going backwards.

Answer (score 0):

PHP $_SESSION is a great, easy fix for storing temporary data (especially if you can't use $_POST).  You only need to clear the SESSION value once, not on every page.

I'm not 100% clear on what you're asking, but try looking at some other values in $_SERVER; they may have what you need.

Comment: I don't remember another solution. Still, if you think that the same user can open several tabs in different pages of your site, you'll understand that the mechanism is not possible to be 100% accurate. Instead of using 2 page, why not only 1 page but with hidden 'divs' for each step?

Comment: how can i clear the $_SESSION once? what if user comes from another page, this value still be there. where should i clear it?

Comment: The SESSION is the same for all pages.  Clear it immediately after it's used.  

As for multiple tabs, I think hidden divs would still suffer the same problem.  More specific code is needed for a more exact answer. =D

Comment: @AlfaTeK yes. 'hidden divs' way is better. but what if such structure is already done. and it requires a lot of work to combine it to one page..

Comment: for example after i submit first page. on second i set my session. then go to third page (still don't use session yet), and then again to first. and i fill my post form with data, beacause session are steel set. and i need to do it only when i go from second page to first.

Comment: How do you know when he goes back to the first page that he wants to create a new post?  Wherever you determine that, also clear the SESSION.